# Differences in import expressions?

Tags: python, django

I have a question regarding the import//from statement in python.

In my views.py file (Project/App/views.py) I have this line:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, ListView
```

Why do I have to include 'django' in that line? Why is it not enough to specify which directory (views) that the generic file is located in? This is what I have done in many of my previous python-only scripts - an example being:

```
from random import foo
```

as well as in my current django url.py file. There, I have:

```
from app.views import view
```

Why don't I have to specify that further, like with the first example where 'django' is included in the path-specification? How come I don't have to write it like this:

```
from project.app.views import view
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the wild world of Python's import system!

To expand on freude's answer a little bit, you've ran into one of the most consistently confusing portions of the Python language: relative vs absolute imports. While the import examples that you gave are syntactically fine, they hide some of the complexity what's going on behind the scenes. When you run:

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, ListView
```

Python searches through the PYTHONPATH (which you can see with something like `print(sys.path)`) for a package or module named *django*. It end up finding one somewhere among your installed libraries. Similarly, when you run:

```
from project.app.views import view
```

It searches those *same paths*, but instead finds the *project* package in the directory that the Python interpreter is currently executing in. However, if you had installed a library named *project*, how would it know which one you actually meant? This is generally solved by using *absolute* imports and by being explicit if you intend to use *relative* imports like this. If you wanted to be more precise in your example, you would specify that you wanted to import it *relative* to the current module by using a `.` - like so:

```
from .project.app.views import view
```

You can even see this in action in an example in the [django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/intro/tutorial01/).

See [this classic answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time#14132912) on the subject for more detailed information.

Answer (score 0):

A python script sees certain paths pointing to the the global default location like `site-packages` or `dist-packages` (you may find those directories in the python directory tree and `random` and `django` are located in one of them) or specified by the environment variable `PYTHONPATH`. Usually, `PYTHONPATH` includes your project directory (*actually you may add there whatever directory you want*). Your example suggests that the packages `django` as well as `apps` and `random` are located in those paths while `project` is not there. In python a package is represented by a directory containing `__init__.py` file as well as some other files representing modules. Now you may import modules from packages in those locations using relative paths like you have shown in your examples.